# Qt opengl glTexImage2D in a widget

Tags: opengl, qt

I was doing an OpenGL display, where I render in an opengl context (GLUT).

But now I would like to integrate it into a big project that does not use the Qt OpenGL API at all (QGLWidget, QOpenGLWidget, …).

So I would have to display on QWidget for example using the function glTexImage2D () because it can take a Qimage input ((GLvoid *) Qimage.bits ())

Comment: You can bind the current framebuffer to a texture using the function glFramebufferTexture2D().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onpenGL in QT widget without QGLWidget and QOpenGLWidget](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/173850/onpengl-in-qt-widget-without-qglwidget-and-qopenglwidget)

Comment: Ok but wath is the difference with a PBO. Usualy I use a buffer like this : GLuint pboIds[2]

Comment: and with a PBO I already do that the probleme is to link a texture with a qt window I think